# Updating table with datetime 6 hours advance

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder if this is possible I have easily done this with jQuery however I need it on a database that I have no control aside from updating it, what I want to accomplish is update it 6 hours advance let's say time now is 1AM I'd like it to be 7AM

This code works

```
UPDATE ffcko_invoices_payments SET payment_duedate=NOW() WHERE invoice_id=14
```

For getting current date and time but I wonder if its possible to make it 6 hour advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple in MySQL:

```
UPDATE ffcko_invoices_payments
    SET payment_duedate = NOW() + interval 6 hour
    WHERE invoice_id = 14;
```

Comment: omg this simple i better read documentations and manuals now ... thank you @gordon linoff

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server

```
UPDATE ffcko_invoices_payments
SET payment_duedate = DATEADD(HOUR,6,GETDATE())
WHERE invoice_id = 14
```